# Limit points of $\cos n$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

> Find the limit point of the sequence $\{s_n\}$ given by $s_n=\cos n $.

I know by this post [Limit of sequence $s_n = \cos(n)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/697145/limit-of-sequence-s-n-cosn) that the sequence does not converge. But I don't know how to search those points.

Comment: You'll be surprised to learn that the answer is $[-1,1]$ ! Can you think of a proof ?

Comment: There's one fact that might be unfamiliar to you but will help with the proof: the sequence of fractional parts $1/\pi-\lfloor1/\pi\rfloor$, $2/\pi-\lfloor2/\pi\rfloor$, ..., $n/\pi-\lfloor n/\pi\rfloor$, ... is dense in the interval $[0,1)$ - meaning that every tiny subinterval $(a,b)\in[0,1)$ contains infinitely many elements of the sequence. This follows from the fact that $1/\pi$ is irrational.

Comment: Why this set is dense on $[0,1)$?

Comment: @G.T.R after I have been thinking about this problem for a while but I get stuck. Can you give me a hint?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The set $A=\{n+2\pi k:n,k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is dense on $\mathbb{R}$. Given a $y\in[-1,1]$ there existe an $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\cos x=y$. Since $A$ is dense on $\mathbb{R}$ there existe a sequence $s_m=n_m+2\pi k_m$ of elements in $A$ such that $\lim\limits_{m\rightarrow\infty}s_m=x$. Then $$\lim\limits_{m\rightarrow\infty}\cos {n_m}=\lim\limits_{m\rightarrow\infty}\cos(n_m+2\pi k_m)=\cos \left(\lim\limits_{m\rightarrow\infty}(n_m+2\pi k_m)\right)=\cos x=y.$$ This implies that the limits points of $\cos n$ is all point in $[-1,1]$.

Comment: The claim in the first sentence is (more or less) proved in an answer to the following [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/272545/15416)