# Questions about the set of sequential limits of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Let $x$ be a sequence. $S(x)$ is the set of all finite subsequential
> limits of $x$. $S^{'}(x)$ is the set of all subsequential limits of
> $x$, that is $+\infty$ and $-\infty$ can also be included.
>
> (i) Investigate whether $S(x)$ and $S^{'}(x)$ may be empty or not.
>
> (ii) What are the possible cardinal numbers of $S(x)$ and $S^{'}(x)$?
>
> (iii) Show that if $S(x)$ is not upper bounded then $+\infty \in S^{'}(x)$. Similarly, show that if $S(x)$ is not lower bounded then
> $-\infty \in S^{'}(x)$.

My attempt:

(i) $S(x)$ can be empty for example for $x_n=n$. But $S^{'}(x)$ is never empty. If $x$ is not bounded below, then $-\infty \in S^{'}(x)$. If $x$ is not bounded above, then $+\infty \in S^{'}(x)$. And if $x$ is bounded above and below, it must have a convergent subsequence, thus a subsequential limit.

(ii) The size of these two sets differ by at most 2, so analysing one of them is enough. $S(x)$ can have size $n$ for any finite $n$ since the sequence $1,2,...,n-1,n,1,2,...$ has subsequential limits $1,2,...,n$. It can also be countably infinite by looking at the sequence $1,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4$. But I am unsure of uncountably infinite case, so I need help for this.

(iii) For this question, I am not sure how to begin. So a hint or a solution would be perfect.

Comment: For *(ii)*, try $x_n=\cos(n)$, where we have $S(x)=[-1,1]$ (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/843664/259363) question). For *(iii)*, use that the limsup and the liminf are **extremal** limit points.

Comment: Concerning (ii), the really interesting question arises whether, in a model where the continuum hypothesis is false, we can have $\aleph_0 < \operatorname{card} S(x) < \mathfrak{c} = 2^{\aleph_0}$. (The answer is no.)

Comment: To follow-up on @Daniel Fischer's comment, any nonempty closed subset of $[-\infty, \,+\infty]$ can be (exactly) the set of subsequence points of a sequence, and it's been known since the early 1880s (Cantor) that infinite closed sets can only have cardinalities $\aleph_0$ or $2^{\aleph_0}.$ See [Given closed $C \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ find a sequence with subsequences convergent to every point in $C$ and nowhere else](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/74632/13130).