# Prove $\cos(n)$ does not converge as $n$ tends to infinity

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, trigonometry, convergence-divergence, epsilon-delta

How do I go about proving that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \cos(n)$ does not exist where $n\in \mathbb{N}$ using an $\epsilon-N$  style method?

Comment: Hint: each interval $(n\pi-1/2,n\pi+1/2)$ contains an integer.

Comment: The hint is for the question in your title. You would not go about proving the claim in the post body.

Comment: @DavidMitra You scared me. I read only the question in the body, then saw your comment as if the statement was true and I was thinking I had been missing on some really fundamental for many years.

Comment: I don't get it. Question body and title ask two different things!

Comment: Some related posts: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/697145/limit-of-sequence-s-n-cosn, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/843664/limit-points-of-cos-n, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136897/what-is-limsup-limits-n-to-infty-cos-n-when-n-is-a-natural-number, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27218/prove-that-the-limit-of-sin-n-as-n-rightarrow-infty-does-not-exist

Comment: [Also related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/967548/how-to-show-that-sinn-does-not-converge). Martin Sleziak posted a better one though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Suppose $\{\cos(n)\}$ converges to $\alpha$. Then $\{\sin(n)\}$ also converges to some $\beta$ such that $$\tag{1}\alpha^2+\beta^2=1$$ since $\sin^2(n)+\cos^2(n)=1$. On the other hand, (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities))$$\cos(n+1)=\cos(n)\cos(1)-\sin(n)\sin(1)$$ and $$\sin(n+1)=\sin(n)\cos(1)+\cos (n)\sin(1)$$
which implies that 
$$\tag{2}\alpha=\alpha\cos(1)-\beta\sin(1)$$ and 
$$\tag{3}\beta=\beta\cos(1)+\alpha\sin(1).$$
But we can see that $(1)$, $(2)$ and $(3)$ contradict to each other.

Comment: the convergence of $\cos(n)$ only guarantees the convergence of $|\sin(n)|$

Answer (score 10):

**(Similar to Paul's answer)**

Suppose towards contradiction that $\cos(n) \to r$ for some $r$.
Then $\cos(n+1) \to r$ also.
Moreover, the identity
$$
\sin(n) = \frac{\cos(n)\cos(1) - \cos(n + 1)}{\sin(1)}
$$
implies that $\sin(n)$ converges, so say it converges to some real number $s$.

Taking the limit of the identity $\cos^2 n + \sin^2 n = 1$, we get that $r^2 + s^2 = 1$.
On the other hand, taking the limit of the identity $\cos((n+1) - n) = \cos (n+1) \cos (n) + \sin(n+1) \sin (n)$, we get $r^2 + s^2 = \cos 1$.
Hence, $\cos 1 = 1$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: And why do you post an answer that is similar to an answer posted one and a half year ago?

Comment: @miracle173 I wrote it elsewhere, so it was no effort to transfer it to here. In my judgment, it added to the existing answers. No need to be so confrontational. There's a lot of *actually bad* content you could be complaining about.

Comment: +1. This answer is certainly better and is lot easier to understand

Answer (score 0):

Use periodicity of $\cos x$: assume $\exists$ L s.t. $|f(x) - L| <0.1 \ \forall x>x_0$. Let's take $x_0= \frac{\pi}{2} + 2 \pi k$ s.t. $\cos x_0 = 0$, so we get $-0.1<L<.1$.

Then, certainly,$-0.1<\cos (x_0 +\frac{\pi}{2})-L|<0.1 \to -0.1<-1-L<0.1$ and we find that $-1.1<L<-0.9$, which is a contradiction. Hence, L doesn't exist.

Comment: The sequence is $(\cos n)$, where $n$ ranges through the positive (or nonnegative) integers. (Also, $\cos x_0=\pm 1$.)

Comment: but it should hold $\forall x>x_0$, not just integers

Comment: Hmm. I took the sequence in the OP to be $(\cos(1), \cos(2),\cos(3),\ldots)$. Perhaps I misinterpreted...

Comment: If the $\epsilon$-bound holds for some integer $\cos (k)$, it has to hold for $\cos (2 \pi k + \frac{\pi}{2})$